# Error When Attempting to $ajax post to authorize.net API with XML Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, api, authorize.net

I am currently trying to make a request to the Authorize.net AIM api. I have successfully sent the post in Post Man. The issue I am having has to do with the fact that the posted data has to be in xml. When I try to set the data to xml as shown in the sample below, I receive an error of Unexpected token ILLEGAL. Any help with this error would be great. Additionally if there is a better way to format the xml for the post please let me know I have looked around allot with no success.

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api",
    data     : "<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>xxxxxxxxxxx</name>
    <transactionKey>xxxxxxxxxxx</transactionKey>
   </merchantAuthentication>
  <refId>123456</refId>
  <transactionRequest>
    <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
    <amount>5</amount>
    <payment>
      <creditCard>
        <cardNumber>5424000000000015</cardNumber>
        <expirationDate>1220</expirationDate>
        <cardCode>999</cardCode>
      </creditCard>
    </payment>
    <order>
     <invoiceNumber>INV-12345</invoiceNumber>
     <description>Product Description</description>
    </order>
    <lineItems>
      <lineItem>
        <itemId>1</itemId>
        <name>vase</name>
        <description>Cannes logo </description>
        <quantity>18</quantity>
        <unitPrice>45.00</unitPrice>
      </lineItem>
    </lineItems>
    <tax>
      <amount>4.26</amount>
      <name>level2 tax name</name>
      <description>level2 tax</description>
    </tax>
    <duty>
      <amount>8.55</amount>
      <name>duty name</name>
      <description>duty description</description>
    </duty>
    <shipping>
      <amount>4.26</amount>
      <name>level2 tax name</name>
      <description>level2 tax</description>
    </shipping>
    <poNumber>456654</poNumber>
    <customer>
      <id>99999456654</id>
    </customer>
    <billTo>
      <firstName>Ellen</firstName>
      <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
      <company>Souveniropolis</company>
      <address>14 Main Street</address>
      <city>Pecan Springs</city>
      <state>TX</state>
      <zip>44628</zip>
      <country>USA</country>
    </billTo>
    <shipTo>
      <firstName>China</firstName>
      <lastName>Bayles</lastName>
      <company>Thyme for Tea</company>
      <address>12 Main Street</address>
      <city>Pecan Springs</city>
      <state>TX</state>
      <zip>44628</zip>
      <country>USA</country>
    </shipTo>
    <customerIP>192.168.1.1</customerIP>
    <transactionSettings>
      <setting>
        <settingName>testRequest</settingName>
        <settingValue>false</settingValue>
      </setting>
    </transactionSettings>
    <userFields>
      <userField>
        <name>MerchantDefinedFieldName1</name>
        <value>MerchantDefinedFieldValue1</value>
      </userField>
      <userField>
        <name>favorite_color</name>
        <value>blue</value>
      </userField>
    </userFields>
  </transactionRequest>
</createTransactionRequest>",
    dataType : "xml",
    success  : function(msg){
        console.log("success");
    }
    error    : function(msg) {
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: Look at the double quotes in the XML that occur inside your double-quoted string.  This will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PHP to make the request and I was able to form the xml as a string using single quotes around the xml as in this sample.

```
$retCustXml = '
        <createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
          <merchantAuthentication>
            <name>'.$loginID.'</name>
            <transactionKey>'.$transactionKey.'</transactionKey>
          </merchantAuthentication>
          <refId>1234546</refId>
          <transactionRequest>
            <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
            <amount>'.$amount.'</amount>
            <profile>
              <customerProfileId>'.$customerProfileId.'</customerProfileId>
              <paymentProfile>
                <paymentProfileId>'.$paymentProfileId.'</paymentProfileId>
              </paymentProfile>
            </profile>
            <order>
              <invoiceNumber>'.$invoiceNumber.'</invoiceNumber>
              <description>'.$description.'</description>
            </order>
          </transactionRequest>


 </createTransactionRequest>
```

'; 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Luke you can post your request in JSON now, Authorize.Net supports JSON, here is a sample charge credit card request for Authorize.net

```
{
    "createTransactionRequest": {
        "merchantAuthentication": {
            "name": "API_LOGIN_ID",
            "transactionKey": "API_TRANSACTION_KEY"
        },
        "refId": "123456",
        "transactionRequest": {
            "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
            "amount": "5",
            "payment": {
                "creditCard": {
                    "cardNumber": "5424000000000015",
                    "expirationDate": "1220",
                    "cardCode": "999"
                }
            },
            "lineItems": {
                "lineItem": {
                    "itemId": "1",
                    "name": "vase",
                    "description": "Cannes logo",
                    "quantity": "18",
                    "unitPrice": "45.00"
                }
            },
            "tax": {
                "amount": "4.26",
                "name": "level2 tax name",
                "description": "level2 tax"
            },
            "duty": {
                "amount": "8.55",
                "name": "duty name",
                "description": "duty description"
            },
            "shipping": {
                "amount": "4.26",
                "name": "level2 tax name",
                "description": "level2 tax"
            },
            "poNumber": "456654",
            "customer": {
                "id": "99999456654"
            },
            "billTo": {
                "firstName": "Ellen",
                "lastName": "Johnson",
                "company": "Souveniropolis",
                "address": "14 Main Street",
                "city": "Pecan Springs",
                "state": "TX",
                "zip": "44628",
                "country": "USA"
            },
            "shipTo": {
                "firstName": "China",
                "lastName": "Bayles",
                "company": "Thyme for Tea",
                "address": "12 Main Street",
                "city": "Pecan Springs",
                "state": "TX",
                "zip": "44628",
                "country": "USA"
            },
            "customerIP": "192.168.1.1",
            "transactionSettings": {
                "setting": {
                    "settingName": "testRequest",
                    "settingValue": "false"
                }
            },
            "userFields": {
                "userField": [
                    {
                        "name": "MerchantDefinedFieldName1",
                        "value": "MerchantDefinedFieldValue1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "favorite_color",
                        "value": "blue"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```